# Vue not updating a component because it's defined outside of this instance?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to use Vue as an implementation for my shopping cart.

The breakdown of what happens:

1. In an immediately invoked anonymous function, an api call is made to parse an updated list of my products into an object and set into local storage.
2. Functions, updateCart and addToCart are in an cartStorage object per a tutorial I saw here: [Vue Tutorial](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/todomvc.html)
3. Vue instance is created binding the data to my cart

Error: Method "items" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render and nothing renders

Code:

IIAF:
var storage = window.localStorage;

```
    (function() {
        var url = "http://shop.domeha.com/api/v1/products.json";
        $.get(url , function() {
            console.log('Running...')
        })
        .fail(function(err){
            console.log(err)
        })
        .done(function(res) {
            console.log(res)

            var products = res.products.map(function(element) {
                return {
                        name: element.name, 
                        image: element.master.images[0].small_url,
                        id: element.id,
                        price: parseFloat(element.price), 
                        display_price: element.display_price 
                }
            }) // End Map

            products = {
                products: products
            }

            products = JSON.stringify(products);
            storage.setItem('domehaProducts', products)
            console.log('success: ' + products)
        })
        .always(function(res) {
            console.log('Done with: ' + res.body)
        }) }());`
```

Object and Vue Instance with Watch:

```
 var cartStorage = {
        fetch: function() {
            var cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('domehaCart'))
        },
        addToCart: function (id) {
            q = $('.shopify-buy__quantity').val();
            q = parseInt(q);
            // if key exists
            if (storage.getItem('domehaOrder') != undefined) {
                var order = storage.getItem('domehaOrder')
                order = JSON.parse(order)

                            console.log("idFilter: " + id)
                            //Returns the ID
                            strID = id.toString();
                            
                            
                            filteredOrder = order.items.filter(function(e) {
                                return e.productID == strID;
                            })

                            console.log("filtered" + JSON.stringify(filteredOrder))

                            

                            if (filteredOrder.length == 0) {
                                order.items.push({"productID": id, "quantity": q})
                            } else {
                            // Returns eveything but the ID
                                newArray = order.items.filter(function(e) {
                                    return e.productID != strID;
                                });

                                console.log("newArray" + JSON.stringify(newArray))
                                order = {
                                    items: newArray
                                };
                                console.log("Q: " + JSON.stringify(filteredOrder[0]))
                                q = parseInt(filteredOrder[0].quantity) + q;
                                order.items.push({"productID": id, "quantity":q});
                            }
                            
                                order = JSON.stringify(order)
                                console.log('order: ' + order)
                                storage.setItem('domehaOrder', order)
                                updateCart()



                        } else { 
                            var order = {items: []}
                            order.items.push({"productID": id, "quantity": q})
                            console.log('order: ' + order)
                            order = JSON.stringify(order)
                            storage.setItem('domehaOrder', order)
                            updateCart()
                        } // else 
                },

                updateCart: function() {
                            // if key exists
                        if (storage.getItem('domehaOrder') != undefined) {
                            //jQuery('.quantity').css('display', 'inline-block')
                            //jQuery('.top-cart-item-image').css('display', 'block')
                            
                            //Get local storage order
                            var order = storage.getItem('domehaOrder')

                            //get local storage products
                            
                            
                            // Parse existing order & products// local storage Must be string
                            order = JSON.parse(order);
                            console.log(order)
                            
                            //Get product data from spree backend
                            storeobj = JSON.parse(storage.getItem('domehaProducts'));
                            console.log("Store: " + JSON.stringify(storeobj))
                            

                            

                        // Merge products and cart data
                        var domecart = order.items.map(function(item) {
                        merge = storeobj.products.filter(function(prod) {
                                return prod.id == item.productID;
                            })[0];
                            return Object.assign(item, { images: merge.image, name: merge.name, price: merge.display_price, intPrice: merge.price});
                        });
                        
                        console.log("cart "+ JSON.stringify(domecart))
                        //Grab Total    
                        var total = domecart.map(function(a) {return a.intPrice * a.quantity}).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
                        total = Number(total).toFixed(2);
                        

                        var quantity = domecart.map(function(a) {return a.quantity}).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
                        console.log(quantity)
                        // Refactor for KO

                        domecart = domecart.map(function(e) {
                            return {
                                price: "$" + e.intPrice * e.quantity,
                                images: e.images,
                                name: e.name,
                                quantity: e.quantity,
                                id: e.productID
                            }
                        });

                        console.log("domecart" + domecart)
                        newcart = {
                            items: domecart, 
                            total: "$" + total,
                            quantity: "x " + quantity,
                        }
                        console.log("final cart" + JSON.stringify(newcart))
                        //// Bind to KO
                        
                        //Strinify and save for later
                        domecart = JSON.stringify(newcart)
                        storage.setItem('domehaCart', domecart)

                        } else {
                            // Cart is empty
                            jQuery('#cart').html("<h1 style='text-align:center; padding:2rem;'>The cart is empty</h1>")
                        }
                    }
                } 
        cartStorage.updateCart();
        var vue = new Vue({
            el: '#cart',
            data: {
                cart: cartStorage.fetch()
               },
            watch: {
                cart: {
                    handler: function(cart) {
                        cartStorage.updateCart()
                    },
                    deep: true
                }
            }
        });`
```

Now, if you don't want to go thorugh all those functions, the update cart, ajaxcall and addToCart all work....

The desired behavior is when a button is clicked
`<button onclick="cartStoreage.addToCart(id)</button>`

The cart will automatically update with the new quantities.

The cart object looks like this: `{"items":[{"price":"$499.97","images":"https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dome-web-assets/spree/images/attachments/000/000/002/small/zwave-group.png?1495122722","name":"Dealer Bundle","quantity":1,"id":1},{"price":"$13341.99","images":"https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dome-web-assets/spree/images/attachments/000/000/003/small/siren.jpg?1495298098","name":"Siren Sensor","quantity":267,"id":2}],"total":"$13841.96","quantity":"x 268"}`

Vues devtools plugin has the cart as undefined and also the fetch() function does get called rught before vue throws that error...

How can I fix this?

Comment: `fetch` is a function that sets a local variable and doesn't return anything.

Comment: Oh geez. You're right...

Comment: @RoyJ When I return that, the error is still there, Vue dev-tools has the value now from the where it didn't before. The data still don't render

Comment: Do you still get the error about `method "items"...`? Update the question to show your fixed code and current situation.

Comment: Also, I think you need to show some HTML. The message indicates that it's a use of "items" in the render that is causing the problem. This sounds like you're starting out with a cart that is not an object with an `items` member (possibly undefined or null).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it was able to be fixed. The issue was with the timing of fetch. If the logic was applied directly to the data object it worked perfectly. Then came the issue of Vue did not detect changes to the object so all of those functions went into vue and updated the vue object where vue listened for changes and then updated local storage.